# What am I comparing when comparing 2 gameObjects?

Tags: unity-game-engine, if-statement

In unity when I compare 2 gameObjects in a if statement.
example: if(this.gameObject == pointerToThis.gameObject)
what is it comparing and how does it know other GameObjects which are almost the same but, not the same are not the same objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It compares if both object references are referring to the same object.
See
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_eq.html

Comment: Thank you! stuff I was googling was bringing me anything this useful.